# How to loop through a text file with lines consisting of multiple numbers, while counting the numbers

Tags: loops, go

The file looks something like:

```
John Smith
100 90 80 90
50 60 80 99 40 20
```

But there can be any number of people/grades in the file. I know how to loop through and get the first and last name of the person, but how can I loop through the first line of numbers, add them to their own total, then loop through the second line and add them to another total?

I've not found a way to check for the end of a line in Go, so I don't know how to distinguish the first line of numbers from the second line.

This is what I've tried:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt" 
    "os"
    "log"
    "bufio"
    //"unicode"
    //"container/list"
)

type Student struct {
    FirstName string
    LastName string
}


func main(){
    fmt.Println("What is the name of your file?\n")
    var filename string
    fmt.Scan(&filename)

    file, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    scanner.Split(bufio.ScanWords)
    //var scanCount int = 0
    //var studentCount = 1
    //var gradeSum = 0
    //var gradeAvg = 0

    var students [100]Student

    for scanner.Scan() {
        students[0].FirstName = scanner.Text()
        students[0].LastName = scanner.Text()
        fmt.Println(students[0].FirstName)

        //count ++

    }

}
```

This is what I have so far. Everything I've tried involving the numbers has not worked so I've removed it.

Comment: Show what you tried so far.

Comment: @CeriseLimón edited it. I've tried more than this but to no avail, this is just kind of a test so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest approach is to loop through the file by lines. Something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

type Student struct {
    FirstName string
    LastName  string
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("What is the name of your file?\n") var filename string 
    fmt.Scan(&filename)

    file, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
     log.Fatal(err)
    }
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        line := scanner.Text()
        if len(line) == 0 {
            // skip blank lines
            continue
        }
        if '0' <= line[0] && line[0] <= '9' {
            sum := 0
            for _, field := range strings.Fields(line) {
                n, err := strconv.Atoi(field)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Fatal(err)
                }
                sum += n
            }
            fmt.Println(sum)
        } else {
            fields := strings.Fields(line)
            if len(fields) != 2 {
                log.Fatal("don't know how to get first name last name")
            }
            fmt.Println("First:", fields[0], "Last:", fields[1])
        }
    }
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

[See it on the playgrOund](https://play.golang.org/p/tRv-ahQSxvL).

Comment: Wow this looks great. Thank you so much. I've done pretty much this exact assignment in java before but I'm just really struggling with learning Go. Thanks again